# SSL certificate occasionally disappears from HTTPS binding

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, certificate, iis-8, godaddy-api

Occasionally, the certificate used to bind HTTPS disappears.
When I try to access the Internet through HTTPS its display: "not possible to reach the site".
Also, when this happens, 2 errors appear in the event viewer window:

1. Schannel error - "A fatal error occured when attempting to access the TLS server cerdential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0X8009030D.The internal error state is 10001."
2. HttpEvent - "An error occured while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:443. The error status code is contained within the returned data."

[Attached link for these 2 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz2kN.png)

Note that these two errors always appear when the server is not working.
The certificate is from GoDaddy.
When I restart IIS the site works again and I can enter it.

Can anyone help me solve this problem? How can I make this certificate binding to stay forever?

Comment: See if you hit the well known issue, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saurabh_singh/ssl-bindings-are-randomly-getting-deleted-for-a-website-with-error-ssl-certificate-settings-deleted-for-port-x-x-x-x443-in-the-event-logs-iis-7-07-5

Comment: This issue is similar but it didn't fix it. the property id="5506" is not in the applicationhost.config file

Comment: Permission issue on a specific file under _C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys_ may explain this behavior. Take a look [here](https://itomation.ca/event-36870-schannel-10001-a-fatal-error-occurred/) to see how you could catch an ACCESS DENIED event at the same time the event 36870 is traced and identify the specific file/required permission.